# Что происходит в методе (POST) контроллера Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, controller

Этот методе вызывается при POST запросе. В целом работа метода понятна. Но, что делает строка `format.json {}` ?

```
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|  
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой способ организации ответа, позволяет вам возвращать разные ответы, в зависимости от формата запроса (оформляется в виде расширения), если это обычный HTML-запрос

```
POST /products
```

то в дело вступает блок `format.html` после успешного сохранения осуществляется редирект `redirect_to`, или в случае ошибки повторно рендерится форма (где вероятно выводится сообщение об ошибке). Если же запрашивается JSON

```
POST /products.json
```

тут срабатывает `format.json` и вместо редиректов, вы отправляете обратно JSON-ответы.

Такое разделение логики часто используется, когда у вас имеет AJAX и обычная обработка одной и той же формы.

Comment: Я предполагал также, но запросы передаются POST /products и POST /products.json (не знаю почему). И как отправить json запрос?

Comment: @jisecayeyo Вообще здесь нет проверки if request.xhr? значит достаточно просто добавить расширение .json в конце запроса, как у вас во втором варианте. Уточнить роуты можно либо через файл config/routes.rb, либо через rake-команду rake routes.

Comment: Запрос передается нажатим кнопки, поэтому через адрес json не получается передать. Если в config/routes.rb прописать, например, post '/products/new', to: 'products#create', то выдаст ошибку, что нету  POST /products

Comment: У кнопки вероятно есть форма или если это <a> есть адрес, который вероятно заполняется хелпером, почти все хелперы, допускают передачу дополнительных параметров, в том числе format: :json

Comment: Вы хотите роуты переопределить? Это возможно, но лучше вероятно задать новый вопрос, в котором подробно описать, что у вас за роуты сейчас и какие хотите получить.

Comment: Переопределять не хочу, просто интересно почему именно на /products нужно делать post зарос.

Comment: @jisecayeyo, может у вас ресурс определен resources :products? Тогда все верно GET /products/new - это форма создания, а POST /products - это обработчик формы create. Тогда JSON будет POST /products.json (поправил ответ).

Comment: да resources :products. Но когда я заполняю формы и нажимаю кнопку, то запрос передается на  /products, а как сделать, что бы он передавался на  /products.json?

Comment: @jisecayeyo Это зависит уже от того, как реализована кнопка, в большинстве случае достаточно поправить хелпер, добавив что-то вроде format: :json в качестве параметра, но куда точно вставлять трудно сказать, у меня перед глазами нет содержимого вашего представления/вьюхи. Заведите новый вопрос, приложив к нему представление с кнопкой.

Comment: @jisecayeyo вывод в JSON для обычных форм не имеет смысла. Туда надо стучаться через JavaScript, либо рельсовым `remote: true`, либо чем-то своим.